# jQuery mousemove over the div and not page

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I've got an image behind an iPad mini in html and css and what I'm trying to do is make the image slide left to right along with the mouse when the mouse is over ipad mini.

I have got together a small piece of jQuery but the code only works when I use `$(document).mousemove`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGnNF/2/)

**html**

```
<div class="ipad-mini">
</div><!--ipad-mini-->
<div class="ipad-mini-actuators ipad-move">
</div><!--ipad-mini-actuators-->
```

**css**

```
.ipad-mini{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:url(http://i609.photobucket.com/albums/tt179/DiegoSanchez88/ipad-mini-small_zpsb53e2bd8.png) no-repeat;
    width: 220px;
    height:330px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2;
}
.ipad-mini-actuators{
    background:url(http://i609.photobucket.com/albums/tt179/DiegoSanchez88/actuators_zps8b1a7c1b.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 200px;
    height:280px;
    top:20px;
    left:10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var mousePos = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
    $('.ipad-move').css('backgroundPosition', mousePos+'% 0');
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't display any result...

Comment: @Getz The example in the fiddle shows that moving the mouse over white area makes the image continue to scroll. I only want the image to move when the mouse is over the ipad.

Comment: your fiddle is not showing anything no image

Comment: I understand, but i don't see any ipad image in the result fiddle...In Chrome and FF. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is the code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGnNF/4/)

```
$(document).on('mousemove','.ipad-mini',function(e){
    var mousePos = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
    $('.ipad-move').css('backgroundPosition', mousePos+'% 0');
});
```